# Visualising np.reshape for TensorFlow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I have some data that I would like to feed into a convolution neural network.

```
for ranking_list in train:
    home_exp = []
    away_exp = []
    exp = []
    home_team = ranking_list[:16]
    away_team = ranking_list[16:]
    count = 0
    for h in home_team:
        row_h = []
        row_a = []
        for a in away_team:
            count += 1
            ex_h, ex_a = values(h,a)
            row_h.append(ex_h)
            row_a.append(ex_a)
        home_exp+=row_h
        away_exp+=row_a

    exp = np.array(home_exp + away_exp)
    reformatted_training.append(np.reshape(exp, [-1, 16,16,2]))
```

I have a ranking list which contains 32 rankings, 16 of which relate to a home team, and 16 to an away team, hence the list is split into two 16 element lists.

Then every permutation of these rankings is used to generate two values, `ex_h` and `ex_a`.

The picture that I have in my mind is that I want to feed in the equivalent of a `16x16` image with two channels (one for ex_h values, and one for ex_a values).

Is the call that I make to `np.reshape` achieving this, I find it hard to visualise this. I'm also a little confused by the `-1` and why TensorFlow requires a rank 4 tensor.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right that "np.reshape achieving this".

-1 means the size of the first dimension will be calculated automatically as total_number_of_elements/16/16/2.

The four dimensions are respectively: batch_size, height, weight, channels (number of feature maps). There is a batch size, because it uses mini-batch gradient descent.